# Difference between Request.Cookies and Response.Cookies

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I use both of these many times in my code and don't really know what the difference is , if a cookie is set shouldn't it be exactly the same in request and response? and is request going to the the most up to date , or response?

EDIT:

ok , I get the difference between a request and a response, but if I type

```
string a = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookie["a"].Value;
```

it is most of the time the same as

```
string a = HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookie["a"].Value;
```

but I am wondering what is the difference between using the two.

Comment: Is the difference just supposed to be a semicolon `;` ?

Comment: ok, suppose there is a semi-colon there , I will put one , I meant the Response vs. Request - which the title of question shows

Comment: Oh, weird, I could have sworn the two lines both said Request for a while.  Sorry.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

As everyone says `Request.Cookies` are supposed to be cookies coming from client (browser) and `Response.Cookies` are cookies that will be send back to client (browser).

There is <strike>black magic</strike> well documented* code that copies values from `Response` cookies to `Request.Cookies` when you add cookies to `Response`. As result it looks like you have same cookies in both `Request` and `Response`. Note that these copied cookies did not come from the client... so beware of making wrong decisions.

Here is a link to discussion about the code: http://forums.asp.net/t/1279490.aspx. In particular, cookies added in the following way will show up in the `Request.Cookies` collection:

```
Response.Cookies.Add(HttpCookie("MyCookie", "MyValue"))
```

---

*The behavior of cookies getting copied from `Response.Cookies` is documented in the [`HttpResponse.Cookies`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.cookies.aspx) article:

> After you add a cookie by using the `HttpResponse.Cookies` collection, the cookie is immediately available in the `HttpRequest.Cookies` collection, even if the response has not been sent to the client.

Comment: It sounds more like a bug instead of black magic. Why should this copying happen?

Comment: @GabrielBurete - I've added the same link as in your [original question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19557365/response-cookies-show-up-in-request-cookies/19557437#19557437). If you are interested why particular behavior was implemented - I don't know, you may try to ask separate question but generally such archeological questions are closed as non-answerable.

Comment: If you replace an existing cookie with a new cookie, `Request.Cookies[NAME]` will only return one of the cookies (empirically, this seems to be the request cookie).  However, you'll see both cookies if you enumerate the cookies.

Answer (score 4):

The request cookie is what is send from the client to the server (thus what the browser provides). The response cookie are the cookies that you want to place in the browser. The next connection from the browser that accepted the cookie from the response object will provide the cookie in the request object.

Answer (score 4):

The word [Response](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525405%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) is used in Asp.net to send data from the server to the client and the [Request](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524948%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) is used to get the data from the client ( in the form of cookies, query string ) etc.
Example:

```
Response.Write("will write the content on the form which will return to the client");
// Response.Cookies will send the cookie to the client browser.
 Response.Cookies.Add(HttpCookie("MyCookie", "MyValue"))
//and Request.Cookies is used to get the cookie value which is already present in the clinet browswer
```

and as you mentioned

```
string a = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookie["a"].Value;
// I think this will check the cookie which is present in the client browser [ If client has sent the cookie to the server ]

string a = HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookie["a"].Value;
// and this will see the only Response object. If the cookie present in the response object then it will return you otherwise not.
```

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what context.

Request is the data that gets sent to the server with every http request. Response is the response after the request *by* the server *to* the client.