# How to set cookie path for AntiforgeryToken in case of asp.net mvc application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

Can any help me to know how to set AntiforgeryToken cookie path for asp.net mvc4 application?

I followed the MSDN article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/security/xsrfcsrf-prevention-in-aspnet-mvc-and-web-pages

but there is nothing mentioned in it containing how to set the cookie path.

Any code sample will help in this case.

Comment: Please go through this url https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms178194(v=vs.140)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: Thanks @Dharmeshsharma for your response. This cookie is different compared to the default asp.net cookies.

Answer (score 0):

In my application startup.cs, i can set my cookie path as below this may help you .

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Configure the db context, user manager and signin manager to use a single instance per request
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

        // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
        // and to use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
        // Configure the sign in cookie
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Home"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
                // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
            },
            CookieDomain = "",
            CookieName = "cookieName",
            CookiePath = "/"


        });            
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

        // Enables the application to temporarily store user information when they are verifying the second factor in the two-factor authentication process.
        app.UseTwoFactorSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));

        // Enables the application to remember the second login verification factor such as phone or email.
        // Once you check this option, your second step of verification during the login process will be remembered on the device where you logged in from.
        // This is similar to the RememberMe option when you log in.
        app.UseTwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie);

        // Uncomment the following lines to enable logging in with third party login providers
        //app.UseMicrosoftAccountAuthentication(
        //    clientId: "",
        //    clientSecret: "");

        //app.UseTwitterAuthentication(
        //   consumerKey: "",
        //   consumerSecret: "");

        //app.UseFacebookAuthentication(
        //   appId: "",
        //   appSecret: "");

        //app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions()
        //{
        //    ClientId = "",
        //    ClientSecret = ""
        //});
    }
```

Comment: The above code snippet is about the cookie generated as part of authentication process. Whereas in my case I am trying to set the path for the cookie that is generated as part of the Antiforgerytoken.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to configure the cookie path with encapsulation.

```
public static class AntiForgeryTokenExtensions
{
    ///<summary>
    ///Generates a hidden form field (anti-forgery token) that is 
    ///validated when the form is submitted. Furthermore, this extension 
    ///applies custom settings on the generated cookie. 
    ///</summary>
    ///<returns>Generated form field (anti-forgery token).</returns>
    public static MvcHtmlString AntiForgeryTokenExtension(this HtmlHelper html)
    {
        // Call base AntiForgeryToken and save its output to return later.
        var output = html.AntiForgeryToken();
        
        // Check that cookie exists
        if(HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.AllKeys.Contains(AntiForgeryConfig.CookieName))
        {
            // Set cookie into the variable
            var antiForgeryTokenCookie = HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Get(AntiForgeryConfig.CookieName);
            
            // Set cookie configuration
            antiForgeryTokenCookie.Path = "/Path";
            // antiForgeryTokenCookie.HttpOnly = true;
            // ...
        }
        
        return output;
    }
}
```

If more details are needed it is explained deeper in my post in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33679150/how-to-set-the-antiforgerytoken-cookie-path/69787538#69787538).

**SOURCE**

[How to set the AntiForgeryToken cookie path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33679150/how-to-set-the-antiforgerytoken-cookie-path/69787538#69787538)